# Why doesn't my server respond to ping?

Tags: ping

I wonder why my server(s) don't respond to ping?

Check this one: klusteranalytics.com

```
$ ping klusteranalytics.com
PING klusteranalytics.com (50.17.214.205): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
```

But it does resolve:

```
$ curl -i -X HEAD http://klusteranalytics.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/0.8.54
Date: Tue, 29 Mar 2011 05:07:43 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 2527
Last-Modified: Fri, 04 Feb 2011 18:19:57 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because somewhere between you and your web server, they're blocking ICMP traffic.

Or because your host really is offline.

`ping` is not a suitable method of checking if your site is alive. When I run `telnet klusteranalytics.com 80` I get the expected HTTP response, so it's safe to assume that somewhere ICMP packets are being dropped. This is not unusual, but is kinda pointless for a web host.

Comment: Thanks! The default EC2 security groups is not configured for that, another developer thought that was an issue (since he wasn't able to connect to a service).

Answer (score -6):

Because DOMAINS NEVER RESPOND TO PING. Only servers can.

And in your case quite oviously the server is configured not to responst to ICMP messages (which is what a ping is). Or an element in between (a router or firewall) throws it away.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is correct too, but I picked the kind one with no UPPERCASE message ;-)

Comment: No need to yell.

Comment: This is also technically incorrect. Presumably the domain resolves to an IP address, which is present on a server and may ping.

Comment: JamesHannah - he's rude but he's right, and he explains your point of view, too rude though.